# Dealing with question name/number in exam packages

Tags: exam

I quite like `exam` package, but in my use case, each question has a title and a number. The same as the `\section` of an article which has a name and a number. Thus, I would like to display the current question number/or name in the header the same way we use `\rightmark`. Last but not least, I would like the grade table to display the full question name.

In my case the first question is named `Foo`, has the number `1` and its full name is: `Problem 1: Foo`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\firstpageheader{Exam}{}{}
\runningheader{Exam / Problem \thecurrentquestionnumber}{}{}

\newcounter{questioncounter}
\newcommand\thequestionnumber[1]{\thequestioncounter}

\qformat{%
  \addtocounter{questioncounter}{1}
  \large\textbf{Problem \thequestionnumber~:~\thequestiontitle}
  \quad (\thepoints)\hfill
  \vrule depth 1.5em width 0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    % In this table I would like the question number instead of the question name
    \gradetable[v][questions]  \vspace*{10ex}
\end{center}
  
\begin{questions}
    \newpage
    \titledquestion{Foo}[10] % Question 1
    ...\par
    \newpage
    \titledquestion{Bar}[10] % Question 2
    ...\par
    \newpage
    \titledquestion{Baz}[10] % Question 3
    ...\par

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

How can I perform the following using the exam package? Where should I look at?

1. Insert current question name/number in the header
2. Display full name with the question number in the gradetable
3. Deal with both question name and question number

**EDIT**

One possibility is to monkey patch the `exam.cls` by adding the following:

```
\newenvironment{questions}{%
  ...
  \def\@queslevel{question}%
  \def\titledquestion##1{%
    \@bonusfalse
    \def\thequestiontitle{##1}%    
    \process@question
  }%
  ...
  \def\process@question{%
    ...
    \xdef\rightmark{Problem \thenumquestions~\thequestiontitle}
```

But I would like to know if there is a better option...

Comment: Are you going to insert only one question per page? Observe that the header is a page header.

Comment: Traditionally our exams are made of 5 questions each of them corrected by one teacher. So it is very convenient to have one question per sheet (either an A4 or a double A4 sheet). Of course, each question has several parts.

Comment: Note that LaTeX deliberately delays changing \rightmark and \leftmark so that only one change per page is allowed.  You can replace that using `\xdef\rightmark{...}` and instead display the last value set.

Answer (score 0):

This answers most of your questions. (For future readers, you'd better ask one at a time.)

The command `\qtitle` deals with the first column of the grade table.

I don't know how to easily insert the "full" question name in the header. But perhaps it is redundant and the question number is sufficient.

[image: c]

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\firstpageheader{\large Exam}{}{}
\runningheader{\large Exam / Problem \thequestion}{}{}% changed <<<<

\qformat{% changed <<<<
\large\textbf{\thequestiontitle}
\parbox{\textwidth}{\quad (\thepoints)\hfill}
\vrule depth 1.5em width 0pt
}

\newcommand{\qtitle}[1]{Problem \thequestion: \enspace  #1\hfill}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \gradetable[v][questions]  \vspace*{10ex}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{questions}   

    \titledquestion{\qtitle{Everything}}[30] What is the answer to everything?
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
            42
        \end{solutionordottedlines} 
    
    \newpage
    
    \titledquestion{\qtitle{Foo}}[20] Do you know foo?
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
            yes
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
    
    \newpage
    
    \titledquestion{\qtitle{Bar}}[15]Do you know bar?
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
            yes
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
    
    \newpage
    
    \titledquestion{\qtitle{Baz}}[10] Do you know baz?
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
            no
        \end{solutionordottedlines} 
    
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```